# Tensorflow 2 ImageDataGenerator preprocessing_function for semantic segmentation masks

Tags: python, tensorflow, semantic-segmentation

I'm trying to use ImageDataGenerator flow_from_directory to load images and masks for semantic segmentation. Images and masks are png files. Masks 3 classes represented by 3 colors: [255,0,0], [0,0,255] and [255,255,255]. 
An example of a mask:

[image]

I want to load a mask from directory and apply one hot encoding on fly:

```
def one_hot_preprocessing(img):
  # the RGB values printed here have float values 
  #print(img)
  print("shape: ", img.shape)
  print("type: ", type(img))
  return one_hot(img, num_classes)

seed = 1
data_gen_args = dict(
    rotation_range=180,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.2)

image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args, rescale=1./255)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args, preprocessing_function=one_hot_preprocessing)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'train/input',
    class_mode=None,
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
    seed=seed)
mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'train/output',
    class_mode=None,
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
    seed=seed)

# combine generators into one which yields image and masks
train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
```

When I check the img values in `one_hot_preprocessing` function, I see such values as `0.0000000e+00`, `2.5500000e+02` or even `5.3197867e-04`. I don't understand why the RGB values are read such way. My only assumption is that mask generator already applied some augmentation transformations and changed the colors. But how in this case can I get one hot encoded set?

Maybe you can advice some more sophisticated solution how to load a data set for semantic segmentation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `0.0000000e+00` and `2.5500000e+02` are just 0 and 255, right? The only surprising one is the last one, and that could come about because of floating points, maybe?

Comment: you're right, I tried to round these numbers, convert to int, but I'm getting 1 instead of 0 or 254 instead of 255 for some values and also. When I tried to it "hard way" : ```img[img>=127] = 255; img[img<127] = 0 ``` (please don't blame me :D), I got a new color: [255,255,0] which totally confused me. Anyway, changing of RGB values is not what is expected from a file read function

Comment: Could it be because of antialiasing or some other image resizing issue? the preprocess is called after augmentation

Comment: maybe try disabling the augmentation and seeing if there still are weird colors

Comment: [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542918/keras-data-augmentaion-changes-pixel-values-for-masks-segmentation)

Comment: Seems like it is because of the zooming and shifting issues.

Comment: Thank you! I tried without augmentation and it worked. Actually I tried to do so, but I left rotation, which also was causing the issue.But is there a way to rotate image on 180 degrees exactly? This shouldn't cause color change?